# Group by year and month the get value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, group-by, aggregate

I am trying to group a entity result on month and year without succeeding.

**Table:**

---

### | StoreName | Year | Month | OrderCount          |

### | Stockholm | 2014 | 1     | 28473               |

### | Stockholm | 2014 | 2     | 26830               |

**Current result:**

```
[
    {
        "storeName": "Stockholm",
        "values": [
            {
                "year": 2014,
                "month": "januari",
                "orderCount": 28473
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "storeName": "Stockholm",
        "values": [
            {
                "year": 2014,
                "month": "februari",
                "orderCount": 26830
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Wished result**

```
[
        {
            "storeName": "Stockholm",
            "values": [
                {
                    "year": 2014,
                    "month": "januari",
                    "orderCount": 28473
                },
                {
                    "year": 2014,
                    "month": "februari",
                    "orderCount": 26830
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

**Code: (This is the code that handles the grouping)**

```
public static IEnumerable<MonthlyOrdersByStoreResponse> ToMonthlyOrdersByStore(this IEnumerable<OrderMonthlyEntity> orderMonthlyEntities)
        {
            return from order in orderMonthlyEntities
                   group order by new { order.StoreName, order.Month } into grouping
                   select
                       new MonthlyOrdersByStoreResponse()
                       {
                           StoreName = grouping.Key.StoreName,
                           Values = (from q in grouping
                                     select
                                     new OrderDeliveryCountByMonth()
                                     {
                                         Year = q.Year,
                                         Month = new DateTime(q.Year, q.Month, 1).ToMonthName(),
                                         OrderCount = q.OrderCount,
                                     }).ToList()
                       };
        }
```

Comment: Do you have any problems running your code?

Comment: No, the code runs but i am getting the "current result" set when i want "wished result".

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue with this code:

```
public static IEnumerable<MonthlyOrdersByStoreResponse> ToMonthlyOrdersByStore(this IEnumerable<OrderMonthlyEntity> orderMonthlyEntities)
        {
            return from order in orderMonthlyEntities
                   group order by new { order.StoreName } into grouping
                   select
                       new MonthlyOrdersByStoreResponse()
                       {
                           StoreName = grouping.Key.StoreName,
                           Values = (from q in grouping
                                     select
                                     new OrderDeliveryCountByMonth()
                                     {
                                         Year = q.Year,
                                         Month = new DateTime(q.Year, q.Month, 1).ToMonthName(),
                                         OrderCount = q.OrderCount,
                                     }).ToList()
                       };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the result grouped by `StoreName`, then by `Year, Month`:

```
return 
    from item in orderMonthlyEntities
    group item by item.StoreName into storeNameGroup
    orderby storeNameGroup.Key
    select new MonthlyOrdersByStoreResponse
    {
        StoreName = storeNameGroup.Key,
        Values = 
            (from item in storeNameGroup
             group item by new { item.Year, item.Month } into monthGroup
             orderby monthGroup.Key.Year, monthGroup.Key.Month
             select new OrderDeliveryCountByMonth
             {
                 Year = monthGroup.Key.Year,
                 Month = new DateTime(monthGroup.Key.Year, monthGroup.Key.Month, 1).ToMonthName(),
                 OrderCount = monthGroup.Sum(item => item.OrderCount)
             }).ToList()
    };
```